# Filtering dynamic table using dropdown ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a drop down menu which generates dynamic table depending on value selected using jquery ajax and change() function. I have coded for few hours and got it working already but now I have noticed that since I have coded the script using the change function , there is a problem because there is no table generated when I first open the page since the script only runs on change.

How can I resolve this? Is there any solution? Shall I just repeat the code into the  where i append the script?

```
$("select[name='dropdown']").on("change", function() {
$( "#div" ).empty();
 $.post(
"sort.php",
{ id: $("#dropdown").val() },
function(data) {
$("#div").append(data);
}
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger the change after you declare the change handler

Something like:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
  /* your change code*/
}).change(); /* now trigger change to fire on page load*/
```

Assumes the `select` has a value on page load

Comment: Hello yes I have trigger the change but I want it also run the ajax requested php script on default value. When the page is loaded e.g. right now when i selected value 2 / 3 / 4 the table is generated but when I open the page value 1 is on default but the table is not generated. I would need to choose value 2/3/4 then choose 1 to generate the table for value 1.

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work for you. Need to show your code..update question with it

Comment: so what happens when you chain `.change()` to the end? It should make the same ajax call